# External JavaScript don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, external

i have a external JavaScript which don't work in my HTML File and i don't know why Firebug doesen't report any failure.
If i run the JS in my HTML it works perfect.

action.js

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var ochk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][id='oose']");
    var ochk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][id='ov']");
    var ochk3 = $("input[type='checkbox'][id='op']");

    ochk1.on('change', function(){
        ochk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
        ochk3.prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
});
```

and my html
test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("style.css");
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./action.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="box">
            <input type="checkbox" id="oose">
            OOSE
        </div>      
        <div class="bs">
            V
            <input type="checkbox" id="ov">
        </div>      
        <div class="bs2">
            P
            <input type="checkbox" id="op">
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery loaded, load jQuery before using it i.e. before actions.js

Comment: Oh my fault it works now nice thank you very much.

Comment: and yet `If i run the JS in my HTML it works perfect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert jquery with the following code:

```
<script src="jquery_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or you can download the jquery file from their homepage and reference the downloaded file in your document. Here is the link where you can download jquery: https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the jQuery first.

```
<script src="your_jquery_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./action.js"></script>
```